# How can i make a IF statement change 2 variables?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a simple RPG game using batch, and for "attacks" that take away both enemy health and "SP". Here is my current code.

```
@echo off    
set /a HP=10    
set /a SP=10    
echo hp = %HP%    
echo SP = %SP%    
pause nul    
set /p DC= 10 max    
set /a NHP=%HP% - %DC%    
set /a HP=%NHP%    
echo %HP%    
pause nul    
set /a DCE=10    
echo you have %HP% hp     
Echo You can 1. Hit (-1 hp to enemy)  2. Kick (-1 hp to enemy) 3 special hit (-2 hp to enemy and -5 SP to you)
```

Note that HP=Health points and SP= Special points or points that you use for special attacks

And also, The beginning code is just to test a system to take away points., So if you have a better system for that. It would be helpful

Comment: Maybe read the docs... `choice /?`

Comment: can't find your `if`...

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    set /a EHP = 10
    set /a BaseDamage = 1
    set /a SpecialDamage = 2
    set /a SpecialCost = 5
    set /p input = .
    if %input% == 1 or %input% == hit (
     echo you hit the enemy
     set /a EHP = %EHP% - %BaseDamage%
     )
    if %input% == 2 or %input% == kick (
     echo you kick the enemy
     set /a EHP = %EHP% - %BaseDamage%
     )
    if %input% == 3 or %input% == special hit (
     echo [insert dialoge here]
     set /a EHP = %EHP% - %SpecialDamage%
     set /a SP = %SP% - %SpecialCost%
     )
    goto a
```

by the way you should probably add   :a   before echo You can 1.Hit 2.Kick 3.special hit

Comment: There are at least four problems with this code: `if` doesn't have an `or` in `cmd`. You'll get a syntax error with `special hit`. `%input%` is not defined (so every `if` will give you a syntax error). You'll need delayed expansion.